# Simplified Lesk Algorithm with Sense Frequency

Tags: python, nlp, wordnet

I am given a WSD (Word Sense Disambiguation) task. I believe the first thing you would try is the following:

1) The most frequent sense baseline (choosing first synset #1)

2) Simplified Lesk Algorithm

Not surprisingly, the performance of the most frequent sense baseline performed fairly well, whereas Simplified Lesk Algorithm was not as good. Using this observation, I am wondering if you can somehow incorporate frequencies of senses in the Simplified Lesk Algorithm. If the Lesk algorithm takes max over overlap sizes, would taking the max of product of overlap size and frequency of corresponding sense be a reasonable modification, if we are somehow given frequencies of senses (possibly learned from training corpus)?

Comment: (Shameless plug): Did you look at https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/tree/master/pywsd ?

Comment: Sense frequency is a little hard to define though.